# Rust workspace / package / module config issues

Tags: rust

I've got a workspace which defines a package.  In ./Cargo.toml:

```
[workspace]
members = [ "mypackage", ... ]
```

The package defines itself too.  In ./mypackage/Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "mypackage"
...
```

The library defines some useful things.  In ./mypackage/src/lib.rs:

```
pub mod mymodule;  // We'll come back to this later
pub trait MyTrait<T> { ... }
pub enum MyError { ... }
```

The library has an auxiliary module file which does stuff with these.  In ./mypackage/src/mymodule.rs:

```
use crate::MyTrait;
use crate::MyError;
...
```

These fail to compile, e.g.:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::MyTrait`
 --> mypackage/src/mymodule.rs:9:5
  |
9 | use crate::MyTrait;  
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `MyTrait` in the root
  |
help: consider importing this trait instead
  |
9 | use mypackage::MyTrait;  
  |     ~~~~~~~~~
```

That doesn't work either, though; if I try that I get:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `mypackage`
 --> mypackage/src/client.rs:9:5
  |
9 | use mypackage::MyTrait;  
  |     ^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `mypackage`
```

I've tried a bunch of variations, cleaned my workspace, rebuilt, updated the toolchain ... pulling my hair out here.

Workspaces, packages, and modules seem to be the bane of my existence.  I keep running into issues like this, reading and rereading The Book and other resources, and I never really figure out what's going on.

Help?

Comment: Do you also have a `mypackage/src/main.rs` file that has `mod mymodule;` in it?

Comment: I do.  What effect does that have?  I'll be honest, I have read the book a half dozen times and I still don't really grok the "correct" way to declare, define, and use modules...

Comment: If you have a `src/lib.rs` and `src/main.rs` that _both_ define `mod mymodule`, then you need to understand that you have _two different_ modules called `mymodule`. In the 1st one, `crate::…` refers to something from `lib.rs`, and in the 2nd one it refers to something from `main.rs`, which explains why it doesn't find the traits from `lib.rs`. Until you are more at ease with modules, I would advise you to avoid packages that contain both `lib.rs` and `main.rs`, and to create separate packages instead (e.g. `mypackage` and `mypackage_bin`).